# Filling space inside cookie cutter

Tags: boolean-modifier, empty

I'm trying to 3D print a cookie cutter but it has a space in it, I want to fill it but I don't know how, I'm a beginner, it has so many triangles that I don't know what's the best approach.

Thank you everyone for any help! [image]

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try this way, select the outer edge, duplicate and move it down:

[image]

Fill it with <kbd>F</kbd> extrude it:

[image]

move the new piece up until it intersects with the object, then *Face > Intersect (Boolean)* and in the *Operator Box* choose *Union*:

[image]

Recalculate the normals, clean the topology, etc

In your case, in the file you share, you have overlapping vertices, select all, press <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance*. Also, in order to prepare the boolean, select all and <kbd>X</kbd> > *Limited Dissolve*. Fill the edge loop you've created, extrude it, recalculate the normals, move up the extruded mesh, boolean (*Union*), use the *3D-Print Toolbox* addon to check the topology, you'll have some corrections to make.

Final result:

[image]

File corrected: [image]

Comment: Great idea! I tried it but when I try to fill it it doesn't fill it entirely, here's what happens (sorry I don't know how to upload an image in an answer): https://imgur.com/a/75Gk8DO

Comment: what does it give if you press Alt F? or please share your file https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: It's this file [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=2NxJ0Kn9" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/2NxJ0Kn9/)

Comment: I've edited my answer, after the boolean your object will still need some works in order to make it manifold and printable, I've linked the file once corrected, it should be manifold now